# String truncated when assigning to input text value in asp .net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view which has dynamic data displayed. I'm building a string from dynamic data and assigning it to textbox value attribute.But my checkbox value is truncated.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder MyStringBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder("Hello world");
        MyStringBuilder.Append(dynamic data retrieved);
        <input type="text" value=@MyStringBuilder />
```

But when i fetch the value it returns Hello and truncates remaining string.
Any idea where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you don't have quotes around `value` attribute, it is very likely that only the first word of your string is treated as actual value. Try adding quotes around `value` attribute and explicitly call `.ToString()` on string builder object:

```
<input type="text" value="@MyStringBuilder.ToString()" />
```